# Can't debug Outlook add-in project

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a problem in Outlook 2010 add-in project, After first debugging for the project I can't debug it one more, it show me the following warning :

> The following module was built with optimizations enabled or without debug information:
>   {Path to DLL}
>   To debug this module, change its project build configuration to Debug mode. To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on launch' debugger option.

and it didn't take any change I have made.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it didn't take any change I have made"*? Does this mean you added code features that aren't being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug, you need **debug symbols** and **non-optimized code** - make sure you have [**Debug symbols enabled** for your build configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e. `Define DEBUG constant` checked and **optimizations disabled**, i.e. `Optimize code` unchecked.

Comment: its enabled and the optimizations disabled

Comment: What is the name of the active build configuration?

Comment: Try doing a Rebuild (*Clean and Build*) of your solution. It sounds like the assembly used by Outlook isn't the same assembly you are building.

Comment: Its very strange behavior, I have tried same thing in another computer and it works fine...

Comment: It sounds like you have a registry issue. Take a look at your [registry hive for Outlook addins](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264829/175679).

Comment: I didn't find register hive for my outlook addin, but what's the solution for this problem?

Comment: After a build, what is the value of your manifest key in the hive `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins`?

Comment: there is no manifest key in this hive, and also there is no hive for my new add in.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrongly looked at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...the manifest key contains the VSTO file path.. its like this "file:///D:/SourceCode/OutlookAddIn5/OutlookAddIn5/bin/Debug/OutlookAddIn5.vsto|vstolocal"

Comment: I found it...just change the extension in manifest key from .VSTO to vsto|‌​vstolocal...Thank you a lot SliverNinja.